# How to get unbiased estimate for error variance in ordinary linear model

Tags: r, regression, variance, error, unbiased-estimator

I would like to estimate the variance of the error term in the ordinary linear regression model. The obvious estimate is the sample variance of the residuals, however this estimate  consistently underestimates the real value. A simple simulation in R confirms that:

```
    x = rep(0:1, c(10, 10))
    a = replicate(1000, var(residuals(lm(rnorm(20, mean = x, 
                          sd = 1) ~ x)))); mean(a)
    0.9418632
```

This is of course makes sense, since when optimizing a linear model we are actually optimizing this error and the real generating model would always give somewhat bigger errors. However, is there a good way to get an unbiased estimate for this error? One possibility is probably using some kind of cross-validation scheme, but is there any way to calculate this analytically?

Comment: Hint: have you ever noticed the "residual standard error" part of `lm`'s summary output? It is *not* the square root of the variance of the residuals. It's computed with the command `resvar <- rss/(n - p)` in `summary.lm`, where `p` is the "degrees of freedom" reported, rather than as `rss/(n - 1)`, which is what `var` is doing.

Comment: Cool! At least on the example above this works. Thanks!

Comment: It is right.  It will work for any regression problem.